# how to cleanup after response in akka-http complete?

Tags: scala, file, http, akka

i generate a file to send as response. after response downloaded that file.csv  want to delete

```
path("hello") {
    get {
        complete(HttpEntity.fromFile(ContentTypes.`text/csv(UTF-8)`,file.csv))
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this the solution

```
  val source = FileIO.fromPath(file.toPath)
                      .watchTermination() { case (_, result) =>
                        result.onComplete(_ => {
                          file.delete()
                          log.info(s"file Deleted  ${file.getPath}")
                        }
                        )
                      }
     complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/csv(UTF-8)`, source))
```

it working fine fore me